# How can I Perform Jquery Onclick on data came through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to perform onclick on Data came through ajax In my website I have a list of online users which is refresh every second And I want that If some one click on any name and it calls another javascript function.

```
function get_list(){

    college = 'college='+college_id; 
    $.ajax({
        url: "_includes/msg_list.php",
        type:   "POST",
        data:   college,
        success: function(result){
            $("#see_msg").html(result);
        }

    });
```

}

this is my ajax function

">

                                        12:28 PM

Comment: To which element you want to bind the click event?

Comment: can you post the html which is generated?

Comment: If you are using a '<li>' to populate name, so you need to call click function on '<li>' and call function get_list() as callback.